# CamelCase naming in Snowflake tables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This may sound supper petty, buy Snowflake forcing all table names into uppercase has made development rather hard.

tables like

- stagingUserInfoUK
- stagingUserDetailUK
- stagingProduct
- stagingUser

become

- STAGINGUSERINFOUK
- STAGINGUSERDETAILUK
- STAGINGPRODUCT
- STAGINGUSER

Which are rather hard to read. I have the same issue with column names:

- productName
- productCategoryName
- productCategoryId

become

- PRODUCTNAME
- PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME
- PRODUCTCATEGORYID

Is there a way to enforce camel-case on table/column names in the snowflake UI?

Comment: The downside of using camel case is that everyone has to know exactly the case of every named object in order to use it. IMO it is more user friendly to split names into words by using underscores rather than changes of case

Answer (score 1):

[Identifier Resolution](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#label-identifier-casing)

> By default, Snowflake applies the following rules for storing identifiers (at creation/definition time) and resolving them (in queries and other SQL statements):
>
> **When an identifier is unquoted, it is stored and resolved in uppercase.**
>
> **When an identifier is double-quoted, it is stored and resolved exactly as entered, including case.**

stagingUserInfoUK - unqouted

"stagingUserInfoUK" - quoted, when used it has to be always accessed using `""` around the name

Answer (score 0):

If you quote identifiers Snowflake will respect the case you use.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE "CamelCasedTable" ( "CamelColumn" VARCHAR);
```

You should find the object is created as desired.

Taken from the linked page below:

> By default, Snowflake applies the following rules for storing
> identifiers (at creation/definition time) and resolving them (in
> queries and other SQL statements):
>
> - When an identifier is unquoted, it is stored and resolved in    uppercase.
> - When an identifier is double-quoted, it is stored and resolved    exactly as entered, including case.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html